# Create User via API in Azure AD

Tags: api, azure, token

**GOAL**: Create users in Azure Active Directory using our Global Admin account from an API.

**PROBLEM**: Every single way I try, I get "unauthorized".

**WHAT I'VE TRIED:**

- I've been focusing mostly on this: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations
- I've tried as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api)
- the "Authorization Bearer {token}" is problematic -- I can't seem to properly retrieve tokens, using any of the built URLs recommended (ie, combining ClientID & TenantID in the URL.)
- I've tried the relevant portions of [this](https://community.nintex.com/community/tech-blog/blog/2016/10/20/microsoft-graph-api-from-nwc), including creating the app, setting permissions on the app, trying both Web API and Native. I'm able to get a code back, but using it always comes back with Unauthorized.

  - As an aside, I am using Nintex to run this web service, as it is part of my workflow. Typically, web services don't give me issues. So, this sucks.

I'm missing something, here. Any thoughts or direction?

UPDATE: Removed the word "method" - bad choice of phrasing.

Comment: Your link in bullet point one doesn't refer to a method... am I missing something?

Comment: Also, I assume you're an Enterprise Customer in this case and using the Global Admin for your Enterprise Enrolment?

Comment: Also, check that the service principal that's running the Nintex workflow has the appropriate permissions to send an invite.

Comment: We are an enterprise customer, and using Global Admin - yep!

With the workflow, I can test the connection to the web service without even publishing it - and that won't authorize.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to create the auth token.

Comment: For sure - it's the "Get auth token" portion of this article: https://community.nintex.com/community/tech-blog/blog/2016/10/20/microsoft-graph-api-from-nwc

(Posting the article because the code is in steps.. more like approaching URLs.)

Comment: Also - I'd recommend you don't use Global Admin for a service if you can avoid it. I'm not sure how Nintex works, but Service Principals with minimum permissions are the way to travel.

Comment: Have you elevated the global admin permissions per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Microsoft Graph explorer to create user as the global admin, you could use `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`, and the required permission is:

**[Permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference)**

[image]

For the details, you could read [Create user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users).

Comment: Thank you, @Sunny -- this runs into the same problem, though -- the Auth Token. I can't seem to get that with the guides I've tried, above.

Answer (score 0):

Global admin runs as a user by default. To grant access to Active Directory, you need to [elevate permissions in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin).

I'm not convinced you have the permissions to create the user, and that's why I think you're getting the error.

Also, try and avoid using Global Admin. Create a Service Principal and provide more granular permissions.